# image on the right

Tags: graphics

I want to have my on the top right of my resume.
Like this

[image]

```
{\large\bf name SURNAME}    \newline    {\large Paris}  \newline    {\large \href{mailto:}}     \newline    {\large \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in}{www.linkedin.com/in}}  \begin{figure}[t] \includegraphics[scale= 0.2]{abc.jpg} \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: `{\large\bf name SURNAME}
 \newline
 {\large Paris}
 \newline
 {\large \href{mailto:}}
 \newline
 {\large \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in}{www.linkedin.com/in}}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[scale= 0.2]{abc.jpg}
\end{figure}`

Answer (score 2):

I use the new tabular package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {X[l]X[r]},
    cell{1}{2} = {r = 4, c = 1}{m},
    hline{Z}   = {dashed}
}
    Name & \includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image}\\
    Phone number & \\
    email & \\
    linkedIn & 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However I don't know how to get the exact height of total 4 rows. I had to test each height to find which one is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

With `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
Name\\
Phone number\\
email\\
linkedIn\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\hfill\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. this is a simple and effective solution